# how to parse this xml data into table in python

Tags: xml, parsing

I have the following xml and I want to parse it into a table. I have been looking around and did not find a good answer. The difficult parts are:

1. The header and data in different subtree
2. All inner tags have same name (th or td)

| Vaccine | Date | Status | Dose | Route | Site | Comment | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vaccine A | Mon,Mar 15,2019 | Done |  |  |  |  | imm. |
| Vaccine B | Tue,Sep 20, 2019 | Done |  |  |  |  | imm. |

```html
<ns0:text xmlns:ns0="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <ns0:table border="1" width="100%">
    <ns0:thead>
      <ns0:tr>
        <ns0:th>Vaccine</ns0:th>
        <ns0:th>Date</ns0:th>
        <ns0:th>Status</ns0:th>
        <ns0:th>Dose</ns0:th>
        <ns0:th>Route</ns0:th>
        <ns0:th>Site</ns0:th>
        <ns0:th>Comment</ns0:th>
      </ns0:tr>
    </ns0:thead>
    <ns0:tbody>
      <ns0:tr>
        <ns0:td>
          <ns0:content ID="immunizationDescription1">Vaccin A</ns0:content>
        </ns0:td>
        <ns0:td>Monday, March 15, 2019 at 4:46:00 pm</ns0:td>
        <ns0:td>Done</ns0:td>
        <ns0:td>
        </ns0:td>
        <ns0:td />
        <ns0:td />
        <ns0:td />
      </ns0:tr>
      <ns0:tr>
        <ns0:td>
          <ns0:content ID="immunizationDescription2">Vaccine B</ns0:content>
        </ns0:td>
        <ns0:td>Tuesday, September 20, 2019 at 12:00:00 am</ns0:td>
        <ns0:td>Done</ns0:td>
        <ns0:td>
        </ns0:td>
        <ns0:td />
        <ns0:td />
        <ns0:td />
      </ns0:tr>
    </ns0:tbody>
  </ns0:table>
</ns0:text>
```

Comment: with what programming language?

Comment: I use python lxml package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you take care of your namespace, you should be OK with something like this, though it's a bit convoluted:

```
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {"ns0": "urn:hl7-org:v3"}
rows = []
cols = doc.xpath('//ns0:thead//ns0:tr//ns0:th/text()', namespaces=nsmap)
cols.append("ID")

for p in doc.xpath('//ns0:tbody//ns0:tr', namespaces=nsmap):
    vaccine = p.xpath('.//ns0:content/text()', namespaces=nsmap)[0]
    id = p.xpath('.//ns0:content/@ID', namespaces=nsmap)[0]
    date = p.xpath('substring-before(.//ns0:td[position()=2]/text()," at")', namespaces=nsmap)
    status = p.xpath('.//ns0:td[position()>2]', namespaces=nsmap)
    row = []
    row.extend([vaccine,date])
    row.extend([sta.text.strip() if sta.text else "" for sta in status])
    #you could combine the previous two lines into one, but that would make it somewhat less readable
    row.append(id)
    rows.append(row)
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
Vaccine     Date    Status  Dose    Route   Site    Comment     ID
0   Vaccin A    Monday, March 15, 2019          Done            immunizationDescription1
1   Vaccine B   Tuesday, September 20, 2019     Done            immunizationDescription2
```